# Cleaning / hide code from inspect element

Tags: javascript, html

I have an e-commerce website and I don't want people to do phishing from inspect element (F12 or CTRL + U) on my checkout page.

On NVIDIA AI PLAYGROUND web site they was able to clean the hole site and keep only this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>nvidia-research-mingyuliu.com</title>  
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://34.216.122.111/gaugan" frameborder="0" />
</frameset>

</html>
```

The link of the Nvidia clean source code page is: http://nvidia-research-mingyuliu.com/gaugan
I have no idea with language I have to use in order to clean the hole page by javascript or php.

Comment: There's no way to prevent that.

Comment: Anything that's sent to the client can be inspected by the user. Even if it's hidden from the Chrome inspector, they can examine the network data. If you want to hide something, it needs to be on the server.

Comment: And the "clean code" you are seeing just means that you need to click elsewhere. There is nothing actually hidden.

Comment: maybe use only js dom to write the html code and then obfuscate the js code ?

Comment: @SalahEddineMakdour You can still F12-inspect the elements then.

Comment: hmmm idk then, it should be a server side thing or even impossible, good luck trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The Nvidia site uses a `frameset` which loads another page and displays it. The code of this seperate page isn't hidden either. In Firefox it is even possible to inspect the elements of the frame.

Comment: Is it only with Fierfox that we are able to see the source code?

Comment: No, you can see it with most browsers.

Comment: Chrome doesn't show the code on http://nvidia-research-mingyuliu.com/gaugan

Comment: @Danielabsi Yes it does; if you don't see it, you just don't know how to use the browser's features.

Comment: if you mean Ctrl + U or F12 I know if it's somthink else please let me know.